# Should this event handler I have used in react be called a function method or just a method or static function what is it?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react with a course that uses the App component as a class. However, I want to use functions, meaning I can't create an event handler using a class method. So I wonder if `swithcNameHandler` is not a class method, then what is it?

```
const App = () => {

  const switchNameHandler = () => {
    console.log("Collide Air Strike");
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={switchNameHandler}>Switch Name</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's just a standalone variable that contains a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function which is a closure. When you passed `switchNameHandler` in onClick, it is basically a reference to the function. i.e

```js
<button onClick={() => {
    console.log("Collide Air Strike");
  }}
```

But if your function is not a closure meaning it is not accessing or updating the variables (state) in your `App component` then you can extract it from the component.
*Example*

```js
const switchNameHandler = () => {
    console.log("Collide Air Strike");
}

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={switchNameHandler}>Switch Name</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```